# How to Connect SQL Server from c++ project in eclipse IDE?

Tags: c++, sql-server, eclipse, eclipse-3.3

I want to Connect to a SQL Server Database from my c++ project in eclipse IDE. In Microsoft MSDN  i found these links:

[connect use sql server in c++](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/94ab0a86-f3d0-45ee-b384-d905420eb5ff/connect-use-sql-server-in-cc)

[Database Connectivity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/connectivity.aspx)

But i don't understand what to do, i need a way to fetch data from my database, any suggestion?

Comment: Try using `odb`: http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/doc.xhtml